# Maven build failure due to package does not exist, while the package exists

Tags: java, maven

I met a weird problem with Maven build. The Maven version is: Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T14:33:14-04:00)

My project compiles correctly in Eclipse (STS Version: 3.9.6.RELEASE), but when I run `mvn install` from command line, it complains about a package does not exist. I checked my `.m2/repository` and the required package is there.

Even more strange is, if I move the `<dependency>` block to a different location, and save the `pom.xml` file, `mvn install` will be good for the first time, and fail after that, until I move the `<dependency>` block again.

The `mvn` error message is:

```
 package  com.xxx.xxx does not exist.
```

Any clue on what I did wrong?

Comment: I've had it happen that the dependency is still listed in eclipse dependencies, even though it's been removed from the `pom.xml`. Is the dependency still listed in your `pom.xml`?

Comment: I also had this problem and solve it my deleting the .m2 folder from home directory.

Comment: @Mark yes, the dependency still listed in the pom.xml.

Comment: @aka-one I delteed the .m2 completely but still have this problem.

Comment: Check in which jar com.xxx.xxx lies , then using mvn dependency:tree ensure that same jar is listed there and is in compile scope.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj I checked that the jar is in .m2/repositories, and also confirmed that the package and the class is in the jar. Also as you suggested, "mvn dependency:tree" confirmed that the jar is being listed and is in compile scope.

Comment: Can you please include more details like dependency name, artifact id, group id, pom.xml and mvn dependency:tree output etc...  Will help the community to better understand the problem.

Comment: Seems like to be a issue with command, try to use mvn clean install .

Comment: Have you checked on plain command line? Not from inside Eclipse etc. Furthermore other logging output related to artifacts?